# HCF of two integers (a,b) =0

Tags: factoring

Suppose $hcf(p,q) = 0$ , is it even possible to prove that $p=q=0$?

My answer to that is

$x = hcf\left(\frac ph,\frac qh \right)$. We have to prove that $x=0$.

Since $x$ is a common of $\frac ph$ and $\frac qh$, there exists integers $m_a$ and $m_b$ such that

$$\frac ph=x∙(m)_a \qquad     and \qquad     \frac qh=x∙(m)_b$$

and multiplying everything by h gives us
$$p=hx∙m_a \qquad     and      \qquad q=hx∙m_b$$

Consequently, $hx$ is a common factor for $p$ and $q$.

We know however that $h$ is the highest common factor of $p$ and $q$ and so, any other common factor of $p$ and $q$ must also be a factor of $h$. In the end, $hx$ must be a factor of $h$, i.e. there exists such integer y such that h=(hx)∙y

It follows immediately that $xy=0$ for which the only possible solution are $x=y=±0$. By convention, however, it doesn't matter which one to choose when computing the $hcf$ of those two prime numbers. So, this gives us the answer $x=0$, i.e. hcf of $p$ and $q$ is $0$.

Is this explanation correct? If not, how would you write it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it is possible to have the HCF of two integers equals 0.

If *p* ≠ 0, the factors of *p* does not include 0. So 0 must not be the HCF of *p* and *q*.

Similarly, if *q* ≠ 0, the factors of *q* does not include 0. So 0 must not be the HCF of *p* and *q* either.

Now for the final case: *p* = 0 and *q* = 0. If we adapt the definition of factors for integers (rather than natural number), then any integer can be the factor of 0. So, we can always find an integer > 0 that is the HCF(0, 0). So, HCF(0, 0) is undefined (an integer as large as you would like).

Combining all the cases, HCF(*p*, *q*) can never be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the HCF of (12222,0)?

Comment: That would be 1? @user96343

Comment: @iterence: Assume we adopt the definition of factors for integers, any integer is the factor of 0. And obviously, 12222 is the largest factor of 12222. So HCF(12222, 0) = 12222. In general, HCF(x, 0) = x when x > 0. But if we adopt the definition of factors for natural numbers (or simply positive numbers to avoid further debate of whether 0 is a natural number), HCF(y, 0) is undefined for any integer y since the factor of 0 is also undefined. You may take a look at this page for more information: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68272.html

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\ 0 = \gcd(p,q)\,$ is a *common divisor* of $\,p,q,\,$ so $\ 0\mid p,q\ \Rightarrow\ p = 0 = q\ $ because

$$ 0\mid n \iff \exists k\!:\ 0\cdot k = n\iff n = 0$$